# Expand column dataframe nested dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, nested

I have make some tries but couldn't get the goal.
I am completely sure that this is an easy question that someone could fix in a moment.
I am trying to parse a json output to a dataframe but I am stuck in a nested dictionary.
Given this example:

```
{'queryResponse': {'@count': 9364,
               '@domain': 'ROOT-DOMAIN',
               '@first': 0,
               '@last': 4,
               '@requestUrl': 'https://10.71.167.210/webacs/api/v4/data/Devices?.full=true&amp;.maxResults=5',
               '@responseType': 'listEntityInstances',
               '@rootUrl': 'https://10.71.167.210/webacs/api/v4/data',
               '@type': 'Devices',
               'entity': [{'@dtoType': 'devicesDTO',
                           '@type': 'Devices',
                           '@url': 'https://10.71.167.210/webacs/api/v4/data/Devices/3795793',
                           'devicesDTO': {'@displayName': '3795793',
                                          '@id': 3795793,
                                          'adminStatus': 'MANAGED',
                                          'collectionDetail': '<status><general '
                                                              'code="SUCCESS"/></status>',
                                          'collectionStatus': 'COMPLETED',
                                          'collectionTime': '2021-01-12T21:43:02.337Z',
                                          'creationTime': '2016-05-05T10:18:39.182Z',
                                          'deviceId': 3984007,
                                          'deviceName': 'AP-02Expressdamiantellez.carrefour.es',
                                          'deviceType': 'Cisco Aironet '
                                                        '1210 Access Point',
                                          'ipAddress': '10.217.36.112',
                                          'location': 'AP-02',
                                          'managementStatus': 'MANAGED_AND_SYNCHRONIZED',
                                          'manufacturerPartNrs': {'manufacturerPartNr': [{'partNumber': 'AIR-AP1231G-E-K9    '}]},
                                          'productFamily': 'Autonomous AP',
                                          'reachability': 'REACHABLE',
                                          'softwareType': 'IOS',
                                          'softwareVersion': '12.3(8)JEE'}},
```

I have been able to parse to this dataframe:
[df_inventory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3X2C2.png)

I need to modify "PartNumber" (or a new column) to the exact part number included (for example  'WS-C2950C-24').
This is my try:

```
df['newPartNumber'] = df['manufacturerPartNrs']['manufacturerPartNr'][0]['partNumber'].strip()
```

I am getting a KeyError: 'manufacturerPartNr' trying to do it.

This is the df:

```
{'deviceName': {0: 'AP-02Expressdamiantellez.carrefour.es', 1: 'AP-01expressastorga.carrefour.es', 2: 'SW-Viajes-1.elche', 3: 'SW-Express-116-1.expresspuentearce', 4: 'Z-Win2.es.wcorp.carrefour.com'}, 'deviceType': {0: 'Cisco Aironet 1 210 Access Point', 1: 'Cisco Aironet 1210 Access Point', 2: 'Cisco Catalyst 2950C 24 Switch', 3: 'Cisco Catalyst 2960-24-S Switch', 4: 'Cisco Catalyst 4506 Switch'}, 'ipAddress': {0: '10.217.36.112', 1: '10.209.221.111', 2: '10.68.87.145', 3: '10.209.116.125', 4: '10.71.79.52'}, 'softwareVersion': {0: '12.3(8)JEE', 1: '12.3(8)JEE', 2: '12.1(22)EA14', 3: '15.0(2)SE10a', 4: '12.2(53)SG1'}, 'PartNumber': {0: "{'manufacturerPartNr': [{'partNumber': 'AIR-AP1231G-E-K9'}]}", 1: "{'manufacturerPartNr': [{'partNumber': 'AIR-AP1231G-E-K9  '}]}", 2: "{'manufacturerPartNr': [{'partNumber': 'WS-C2950C-24'}]}", 3: "{'manufacturerPartNr': [{'partNumber': 'WS-C2960-24-S'}]}", 4: "{'manufacturerPartNr': [{'partNumber': 'WS-C4506'}]}"}}
```

Could someone help me to get this last step?

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve this issue.
I post the answer if someone could find it usefull.

```
df["NewPart"] = [i['manufacturerPartNr'][0]['partNumber'].strip() for i in df['manufacturerPartNrs']]
```